# Function is skipped in Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have function which take opened tabs and save it into chrome.storage, problem is that I need to execute function **chrome.windows.getAll()** first, but if my function runs it skips function **chrome.windows.getAll()** and after whole function it will jump back to function **chrome.windows.getAll()** and execute it as last.

This is my code:

```
    var new_tabs = [];

    chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows){
      windows.forEach(function(window){
        window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
          new_tabs.push(tab.url);
        });
      });
    });

    chrome.storage.local.set({'tabs': new_tabs});
```

Comment: Since getAll is asynchronous, save the data inside its callback, right after windows.forEach. You may want to see more examples/tutorials of how asynchronous code works.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that it is asynchronous, I would like to save data to some variable which is "visible" to whole function and not only inside its callback.

Comment: There's no point in making it visible because the actual value is assigned only inside the asynchronous callback, which is invoked later, after the enclosing function is completed. See the linked topic for more details.